# Android App: Fragment, Activity, Navigation Drawer structure/architecture

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to using Fragments in Android.

I started developing an app using Navigation Drawer with Fragments, but realised that I'll have more than 1 activity.

Please have a look at the diagram of my current app plan and suggest if there is a better way:

Main Activity, contains 3 fragments (you can navigate to each via the NavDrawer)
Activity 2 will be swipe tabs where each tab is a fragment. However this way my NavDrawer will not have links to this tabs/fragments.

Is there a better way? Should I avoid using a second activity completely? Or does the diagram look logical?:

[image: Current diagram]

Answer (score 6):

My philosophy is:

Avoid creating a "God Activity". So, do not be concerned when creating a new activity. However, only create activities that make sense with your domain logic. For example, I am working on a project with the following structure:

[image]

I have a main activity working with a NavDrawer and ViewPager to make user navigation between the main sections of the APP. Some of these sections allow you to create a new record. For this new "action" I create a new activity that uses other fragments aimed at registering this new record.

That way you can have your main activity with the features that the user needs to quickly navigate and tasks used are less easily accessed by a Floating Action Button invoking the new activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So is there any way for your NavDrawer to have links to Fragments 4,5,6,7?

Comment: Yes, you can create a button in NavDrawer to invoke the fragment. But remember to be very careful, not to let bad smell in your activity code. You will need to control all backstack flow manually. And believe me, it can be hard in some cases. In addition, some Google Apps (like Gmail) has called activities from the NavDrawer too (and not only inflate Fragment)...